# IntelliJ project local deployment configuration for Tomcat- local server root URL

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

I'm trying to get a local Tomcat deployment under control in IntelliJ (version 12) and so looking to configure a local connection to Tomcat.

I try to add a server specifying 'Local or mounted folder'. All seems okay but asks me to specify '**web server root URL**'.

As its a local server I'd like something like '/opt/tomcat/tomcat7-dev' which points to the root of my tomcat install, however IntelliJ logically says this '**URL is not valid**'.

**Any advice on correct way to specify local server for IntelliJ deployment?**

Comment: You don't need this configuration for local Tomcat development, refer to [this document](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Tomcat configuration doesn't require any Deployment settings or mappings, you just configure a server, artifact and a run configuration to start the server and deploy the artifact, [more details can be found in the tutorial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12).